# Regular expression for find the text

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the `My Text Content` that immediately follows `AB.00.000`.

I could able to get this `AB.00.000` by using the below regular expression,

```
([A-Z]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})
```

How do I get the text next to the `AB.00.000` in Python?

Here is the input string:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 

AB.00.000 My Text Content

$!#"!

23:50

My Phone
```

Comment: `re.search(r'\b[A-Z]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\s(.*)').group(1)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: could you please add as answer. so that I can accept the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to get the whole rest of the line after your pattern is found.

You may use

```
r'\b[A-Z]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\b\s*(.*)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwJHya/1). Note that `\b` is a word boundary that requires a char other than a letter/digit/`_` before or after a word char (or start/end of string). 
The `\s*(.*)` is what your solution is missing badly:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Capturing group #1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, i.e. the rest of the line.

If the pattern must reside at the beginning of a line a regex way to extract the text you need will look like

```
r'(?m)^[A-Z]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\b\s*(.*)'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/srlwNE/1). `(?m)` (=`re.M` option) makes `^` match start of a line, not only start of the whole string, position.

Python:

```
m = re.search(r'\b[A-Z]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\b\s*(.*)')
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Note that to access the first (and only here) parenthesized part of the match you need to access the match group via `.group(1)`.